# Recover from system image

Tags: hard-drive, backup

I have two hard drives (1TB and 2TB) with windows installed on the 1TB drive and I would like to replace the 1TB drive with a new 8TB SSD hard drive that I just bought.

I created and saved a backup image on the 2TB hard drive as well as a boot drive on USB.  I restart in BIOS and launch the USB and when I go to reformat and reimage it gives me an option to exclude drives.  If I try to exclude the 1TB drive, it gives me a cryptic error saying I can uncheck that drive but I don't want to reformat that drive or install the image on it.

How do I install the image only on the new drive?

This image is what it gives me if I disconnect the 1TB hard drive when I try to reformat and reimage

[image]

Comment: Which product did you use for creating the USB? How are you installing?

Comment: I have Windows 10 and used the native functionality to create an image and reboot USB drive

Comment: It *MAY* think it needs to write boot blocks/EFI info to that drive. What if you unplug that drive so the system only sees the one (new) drive?

Comment: Try to connect the 2TB with the connector where was previously the 1TB. Verify in the BIOS that it's truly detected.

Answer (score 0):

You might find a third-party tool such as [Macrium Reflect Free](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree) easier to use. These tools not only image and clone disks, but most also can create a [bootable "rescue" USB](https://kb.macrium.com/KnowledgebaseArticle50210.aspx) that will transfer the image to another drive.

Note that restoring or cloning 1 GB to an 8 GB drive might leave 7 GB unformatted, but that is easily resolved afterwards with *diskmgmt.msc* or another third-party tool, e.g. free [DiskGenius](https://www.diskgenius.com/). It takes just a minute or two to expand the 1 GB partition to the full disk size... or to leave some HDD space for another partition.